# How to change variable inside a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to change var2 variable inside Makefile step from 'test2' to 'test3' but var2 do not changes.

```
var1 = 'test1'
var2 = 'test2'

test-if:

    @echo $(var1)
    @echo $(var2)
    @if [ '$(var1)' = 'test1' ]; then\
        echo "equals";\
        export var2='test3';\
    else echo "not equals";\
    fi
    @echo $(var2)
```

If I use `var2='test3'`- without `export` result is the same, var2 do not changes
If I use `$(var2)='test3'` there is an error `/bin/sh: 3: test2=test3: not found`

How I can solve this? Thanks

Solution is like that

```
var1 = test1
var2 = test2

test-if:
    @echo ${var1}
    @echo ${var2}
ifeq (test1, $(var1))
    @echo "equals"
    $(eval override var2 ='test3')
else 
    @echo "no tequals"
endif
    @echo ${var2}
```

it work all good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**
The `make` variables, and the `shell` variables are not the same. Mixing them require following specific rules.

**Long Answer:**

When setting environment variable to pass to commands, there are multiple considerations to take.

- Individual recipes commands (on separate lines) are executed by different command shells (by default). Each recipes command starts with the same setting of the make variables. In particular, the `export var2` does not apply to the `echo $(var2)
- The `make` variables are not always exported to the rules (e.g., `var1 = 'test1'`). The actual rules are described in `make` manual [Communicating Variables to a Sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html)

Also setting make follow different quoting. In particular `var1 = 'test1'` will set the make variables to `'test1'`, including the quotes. The quotes are removed by the shell, when parsing the command.

To achieve what you want, consider two options:

1. Perform the conditional assignment at the make level.
2. Perform the conditional assignment and the print at a single shell level.

**Conditional assignment in make**

Use the make `ifeq`. Notice no quotes are needed for make assignment or conditional.

```
var1 = test1
var2 = test2

ifeq ($(var1),test1)
var2=test3
endif

test-if1:
        echo test-if1: $(var2)
```

**Condition assignment in the shell**

The commands that uses the variables (`echo` in this case) must be in the same shell commands that set the variables (combined by adding `\` to the end of each line. Also, the commands must refer to the shell environment variables using `$$var` instead of the make variables `$var` See [Using $ in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#index-_0024_002c-in-rules)

```
var1 = test1
var2 = test2

test-if2:
        if [ '$(var1)' = 'test1' ]; then\
                export var2='test4';\
        fi ;\
        echo $$var2
```

Which one to use is depends on the situations. make variables are usually easier to work with (simpler quoting), but offer limited flexibility. When the values of the variables is dynamic, there is usually no choice but to use shell variables, and deal with the complexities (quoting, precedence, …)

Comment: Conditional assignment unfortunately  returns error Makefile:5: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.

Comment: Condition assignment unfortunately returns make: Nothing to be done for `test-if2'.

Comment: But I were suggested this solution and it works pretty good:  "ifeq .. $(eval override var2 ='test3')"  Thanks!

Comment: I added my soution in the tast descriotion. Thanks, Mate!

Comment: So, You were ablolutely right the case were  in the mix bach and makefile logics

Comment: @bota4go, If you feel the answer addressed the problem you posted, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers